# how to enable past dates using CalendarDateRangePicker in Xamarin Native Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am using a CalendarDateRangePicker for the date range selection in calendar. Native android library has an option to enable the past dates. But, Xamarin android library does not have an option to enable the past dates and set the selected dates in calendar. Can anyone please help me on this? Link below for the calendar that i am using now..

https://github.com/kibotu/Xamarin.Awesome.Calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the latest version(1.1.3.1). Then add `app:enable_past_date="true"` to axml.
You could check it's [official demo](https://github.com/kibotu/Xamarin.Awesome.Calendar/blob/master/Xamarin.Awesome.Calendar.Demo/Resources/layout/Main.xml).

```
<com.archit.calendardaterangepicker.customviews.DateRangeCalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:enable_past_date="true"
    >   
</com.archit.calendardaterangepicker.customviews.DateRangeCalendarView>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped.